# Как уменьшить прозрачность тени SKPAth в SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, maui

Всем привет, рисую трапецию с помощью SkiaSharp в MAUI через SKPath и решил добавить тень к трапеции:

```
SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
 {
     Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
     Color = SKColors.Black,
     ImageFilter = SKImageFilter.CreateDropShadow(5, 5, 5, 5,
     SKColors.Black.WithAlpha(0xFF)),
        
 };

SKPath path = new SKPath();

path.MoveTo(0, height / 2 - btnHeight / 2);
path.LineTo(0, height / 2 + btnHeight / 2);
path.LineTo(btnBottomSide, height / 2 + btnHeight / 2);
path.LineTo(width, height / 2 - btnHeight / 2);
path.Close();

canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
```

В SKImageFilter запускаю метода CreateDropShadow и передаю ему черный цвет для тени, предварительно указав на полную непрозрачность SKColors.Black.WithAlpha(0xFF), но тень в итоге все равно слишком прозрачная. Знаю что можно скопировать саму трапецию и передвинуть ее, предварительно заблюрив и т.д., но неужели нет встроенного функционала для регулировки прозрачности?

[image: Результат кода]

Comment: Уменьшить размытие тени, увеличить толщину линии?

Comment: 5, 5, 2, 2 попробуйте